# RAW type in Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have got a table with `RAW` type field. How this field should be annotated in Hibernate? And which data type should I use for field in its entity class? Byte array or what? I didn't find an information about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try mapping it to byte[]

If you have an java.sql.SQLException: Stream has already been closed
You have to set your OJDBC driver connection's properties with :

```
useFetchSizeWithLongColumn = true
```